# An old and interesting problem in combinatorics from Russia Mathematics Olympiad

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

*Can the numbers from $1$ to $81$ be written on a $9 \times 9$ board, so that the sum of the numbers in each $3\times 3$ square is the same?*

I believe I have not made much progress and am missing the key insight here. Any advice?

Comment: One insight is that each 3x3 block's numbers have to add up to the sum of all the numbers divided by 9: $\sum_{k=1}^{81} k /9 $. That's not enough to solve the problem but it reduces the number of cases that need to be considered.

Comment: Do you mean all the $3\times 3$ squares in the $9\times 9$ grid (of which there are $49$, I think)?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, all the $3\times 3$ squares.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but I was considering a partition into nine disjoint 3x3 blocks, no overlap allowed.

Comment: @StinkingBishop There are $49$, but they overlap, so you'd be double counting.  You can divide the big square into $9$ disjoint $3\times3$ squares, though.  The sum in each square is $369$, if I divided correctly.

Comment: @saulspatz I am not counting (just yet) - I just wanted to make it clear that we are not considering the $9$ ("Sudoku") smaller squares, but rather all $49$.

Comment: All I have managed to figure out is that the sum of each $3\times 3$ block is $369$, each  $1\times 3$ horizontal block has the same sum as the corresponding one three rows below it, same goes for the columns, two pairs of opposite corners of each $4\times 4$ block has the same sum. Nothing much and I can't continue.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Oh, I misunderstood.  I take it to mean that we consider all $49$ squares, but I can' be certain, of course.  (If we only considered the sudoku square, it would be too easy, I think.

Answer (score 13):

I believe if you take the following matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccccccc}0&3&6&0&3&6&0&3&6\\1&4&7&1&4&7&1&4&7\\2&5&8&2&5&8&2&5&8\\3&6&0&3&6&0&3&6&0\\4&7&1&4&7&1&4&7&1\\5&8&2&5&8&2&5&8&2\\6&0&3&6&0&3&6&0&3\\7&1&4&7&1&4&7&1&4\\8&2&5&8&2&5&8&2&5\end{array}\right]$$

it already satisfies the conditions, and so does the transpose $A^T$:

$$A^T=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccccc}0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\etc.\end{array}\right]$$

and so does an affine combination $B=A+9A^T+1$, where "$1$" is the matrix filled with "all ones". One should verify that the resulting matrix $B$ has all the different values from $1$ to $81$. It begins something like this:

$$B=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccccc}1&13&25&28&40&52&55&67&79\\etc.\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: There are, I believe, some minor typos in the matrix. A 9 in the row seven column eight. An 8 in the row 8 column 4. It's a simple typo, but I can't make an edit because it's less than 6 characters.

Comment: @ACheca Thanks, fixed

Comment: I check this, and it seems to be a correct solution. Can you explain your thought process on coming up with this, and how you can tell that the final matrix has all of the numbers from 1 to 81 present in it?

Comment: @Geoffrey If you decrement all the numbers by $1$ (to get to range $0-80$, and then represent every number in base $9$, you get an array of $2$-digit (at most) numbers. You want them to be all different, but then I went off to try to separately "fit" the first digit and the second digit (knowing that each has to appear $9$ times). Matrix $A$ was pretty much the first fit I tried, and then matrix $A^T$ just did the rest of the job. A bit lucky, I guess. To check, I just wrote all those base-$9$ numbers by superimposing matrices $A$ and $A^T$ and checked that they were all different $00-88$.